# Вывод текста в кодировке сp866 в richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, текст, richtextbox

Получаю файл текстовый файл в кодировке 866, необходимо вывести текст файла в richtextbox.

```
String text = File.ReadAllText(@"...\parametr.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
richTextBox1.WordWrap = false;
richTextBox1.Text = text;
```

Если посмотреть в отладке через визуализатор текста строку text, увидим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все ровно....Но текст в richtextbox сбивается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как научить richtextbox выводить текст так же как визуализатор?

Comment: В свойствах richtextbox смените шрифт на monospace.

Answer (score 0):

Сменил шрифт в ричбоксе на courier new, помогло.

Comment: на любой моноширинный